# How to have a continuous function, running on the blockchain network, updating assets as it runs?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've written the logic to continuously monitor a few assets from my logic.js file on Hyperledger Composer. It does this by having a continuous function running which sends requests to different api's and updates the assets based on the result.

I want this process to run all the time, constantly monitoring all the assets, and updating the assets in the network as it receives results.

What I'm doing now to achieve this is calling the function (`repeatMonitorPlane(planes)`) from my network setupDemo function. One problem with this, however, is that if the network needs to be restarted the setupDemo is halted and when it restarts it doesnt continue monitoring the assets and I cant run the setupDemo again. Does anyone know how to get around this? Maybe there is some system functions where I can call the repeatMonitorPlane function so that if the network is restarted it will kick off the process again?

Any ideas are greatly aprreciated!

My code:

```
   async function repeatMonitorPlane(planes){
  //passing all four planes in ourSetupDemo into monitor plane function
  console.log('Planes being monitored: ' + planes);

  setInterval(async function () {
     try{
          await monitorPlane(planes);
      } catch (e) {
          console.log('\nPlane is on the ground \n');
      }
  }, 15000);


/**
 * Transaction to allow parties to Monitor planes
 * @param {org.blockaviation.MonitorPlane} monitorPlane
 * @transaction
 */
async function monitorPlane(monitorPlane){
    var NS = 'org.blockaviation';

    var location;


    console.log(monitorPlane.length);


    for(i =0;i<monitorPlane.length;i++){
        var monitor_plane = monitorPlane[i];
        console.log("\n"+i+"\n");


            console.log('\nMonitoring plane: ' + monitorPlane[i].icao);
             await getLocation(monitorPlane[i].icao)
            .then(function(location){

                if (location == null) throw "Plane on ground";
                console.log('location in monitorPlane: latitude: '+location[0] + ' longitude: '+location[1]);

                monitor_plane.lat = location[0]
                monitor_plane.long = location[1]

                //update the location variable on the plane asset
                if(monitor_plane.location){
                    monitor_plane.location.push(location[0],location[1])    //lat,long
                }else{
                    monitor_plane.location = [location[0],location[1]]
                }
                }).then(function(){
                    return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Plane')
                }).then(function(planeRegistry){
                    console.log('monitor_plane.location');
                    console.log(monitor_plane);
                    return planeRegistry.update(monitor_plane);
                }).catch(function(e){
                    console.log(e);
                    return
                })

              }
      }

async function getLocation(icao){


    var url = 'https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?icao24=' + icao;

    var lat, long;

    try {

        var result = await request.get({uri: url, json: true });


        if (result.states == null){
            throw "Plane on ground";
        }


        lat = result.states[0][6]
        long = result.states[0][5]

        lat = lat.toString()
        long = long.toString()
        location = [lat,long]
        console.log('Plane: '+ icao + ' location: ' + 'latitude: '+ location[0] +' degrees, ' + 'longitude: ' + location[1] + ' degrees\n' );
        return location
     } catch(e) {
          console.log('\nError trying to get location of plane \n');
          return null
    }

  }
}
```

Logs for `dev-peer0.org1.example.com` -> Problem with updating the asset?

```
4

0


Monitoring plane: 4409c0
Plane: 4409c0 location: latitude: 54.9203 degrees, longitude: -3.0248 degrees

location in monitorPlane: latitude: 54.9203 longitude: -3.0248
2018-04-04T15:31:16.373Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : Api                     :getAssetRegistry()       > org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.373Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : RegistryManager         :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.374Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : NodeDataCollection      :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
Error: [3e973d0c]No ledger context for GetState. Sending ERROR
    at parseResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:673:9)
    at MsgQueueHandler.handleMsgResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:137:26)
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:293:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at readCallback (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:312:14)

1


Monitoring plane: 3c674e
Plane: 3c674e location: latitude: 54.8877 degrees, longitude: -3.5034 degrees

location in monitorPlane: latitude: 54.8877 longitude: -3.5034
2018-04-04T15:31:16.551Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : Api                     :getAssetRegistry()       > org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.551Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : RegistryManager         :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.551Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : NodeDataCollection      :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
Error: [3e973d0c]No ledger context for GetState. Sending ERROR
    at parseResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:673:9)
    at MsgQueueHandler.handleMsgResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:137:26)
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:293:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at readCallback (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:312:14)

2


Monitoring plane: 4ca264
Plane: 4ca264 location: latitude: 53.4304 degrees, longitude: -4.9469 degrees

location in monitorPlane: latitude: 53.4304 longitude: -4.9469
2018-04-04T15:31:16.794Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : Api                     :getAssetRegistry()       > org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.796Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : RegistryManager         :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
2018-04-04T15:31:16.796Z [3e973d0c] [DEBUG   ] @JS : NodeDataCollection      :get()                    > Asset:org.blockaviation.Plane
Error: [3e973d0c]No ledger context for GetState. Sending ERROR
    at parseResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:673:9)
    at MsgQueueHandler.handleMsgResponse (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:137:26)
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/handler.js:293:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at readCallback (/usr/local/src/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:312:14)

3


Monitoring plane: 40742f

Error trying to get location of plane 

Plane on ground
```

setupDemo

```
/**
  * This is jus a setuo demo. It wil create new particpants and assets automatically
  * @param {org.blockaviation.OurSetupDemo} ourSetupDemo
  * @transaction
  */
function ourSetupDemo(ourSetupDemo){

    var factory = getFactory();
    var NS = 'org.blockaviation';


    //Create LESSOR one
    var lessor  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor@gmail.com');
    var lessorAddress = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    lessorAddress.country = 'USA';
    lessor.address = lessorAddress;

    //Create LESSOR two
    var lessor2  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor2@gmail.com');
    var lessor2Address = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    lessor2Address.country = 'Ireland';
    lessor2.address = lessor2Address;

    //Create LESSEE one
    var lessee  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee@gmail.com');
    var lesseeAddress = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    lesseeAddress.country = 'USA';
    lessee.address = lesseeAddress;

    //Create LESSEE two
    var lessee2  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee2@gmail.com');
    var lessee2Address = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    lessee2Address.country = 'Ireland';
    lessee2.address = lessee2Address;


    //Create MANUFACTURER one

    var manufacturer  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer@gmail.com');
    var manufacturerAddress = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    manufacturerAddress.country = 'USA';
    manufacturer.address = manufacturerAddress;

    //Create MANUFACTURER two

    var manufacturer2  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer2@gmail.com');
    var manufacturer2Address = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    manufacturer2Address.country = 'USA';
    manufacturer2.address = manufacturer2Address;

    //Create Servicer one

    var servicer  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer@gmail.com');
    var servicerAddress = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    servicerAddress.country = 'USA';
    servicer.address = servicerAddress;

    //Create Servicer two

    var servicer2  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer2@gmail.com');
    var servicer2Address = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Address');
    servicer2Address.country = 'Germany';
    servicer2.address = servicer2Address;

    //Create the regulator - not extended from member abstract class

    var regulator  = factory.newResource(NS, 'Regulator', 'regulator@gmail.com');

    //Create the first Contract

    var contract = factory.newResource(NS, 'Contract', 'CON_001');
    contract.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor@gmail.com');
    contract.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee@gmail.com');
    contract.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer@gmail.com');
    contract.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer@gmail.com');
    contract.contractType = 'DRY_LEASE';
    contract.contract_status = 'INITIALISED';

    //Create the second Contract

    var contract2 = factory.newResource(NS, 'Contract', 'CON_002');
    contract2.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor2@gmail.com');
    contract2.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee2@gmail.com');
    contract2.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer2@gmail.com');
    contract2.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer2@gmail.com');
    contract2.contractType = 'WET_LEASE';
    contract2.contract_status = 'INITIALISED';

    //Create the first plane asset

    var plane = factory.newResource(NS,'Plane', 'Plane_001');
    plane.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor@gmail.com');
    plane.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee@gmail.com');
    plane.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer@gmail.com');
    plane.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer@gmail.com');
    plane.icao = '4409c0';
    plane.lat = '0';
    plane.long = '0';

    //Create the second plane asset

    var plane2 = factory.newResource(NS,'Plane', 'Plane_002');
    plane2.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor@gmail.com');
    plane2.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee@gmail.com');
    plane2.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer@gmail.com');
    plane2.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer@gmail.com');
    plane2.icao = '3c674e';
    plane2.lat = '0';
    plane2.long = '0';

    //Create the third plane asset

    var plane3 = factory.newResource(NS,'Plane', 'Plane_003');
    plane3.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor2@gmail.com');
    plane3.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee2@gmail.com');
    plane3.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer2@gmail.com');
    plane3.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer2@gmail.com');
    plane3.icao = '4ca264';
    plane3.lat = '0';
    plane3.long = '0';



    //Create the fourth plane asset

    var plane4 = factory.newResource(NS,'Plane', 'Plane_004');
    plane4.lessor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessor', 'lessor@gmail.com');
    plane4.lessee = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Lessee', 'lessee@gmail.com');
    plane4.manufacturer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturer@gmail.com');
    plane4.servicer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'Servicer', 'servicer@gmail.com');
    plane4.icao = '40742f';
    plane4.lat = '0';
    plane4.long = '0';

    //var planes = [plane,plane2,plane3];//,plane2,plane3,plane4
    var planes = [plane,plane2,plane3,plane4];//
    //console.log('plane');
    //console.log(plane);
    repeatMonitorPlane(planes)




    //Create the javascript promises - Populating contract
    return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Lessor')
        .then(function(lessorRegistry){
            return lessorRegistry.addAll([lessor,lessor2]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Lessee');
        })
        .then(function(lesseeRegistry){
            return lesseeRegistry.addAll([lessee,lessee2]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Manufacturer');
        })
        .then(function(manufacturerRegistry){
            return manufacturerRegistry.addAll([manufacturer,manufacturer2]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Servicer');
        })
        .then(function(servicerRegistry){
            return servicerRegistry.addAll([servicer,servicer2]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getParticipantRegistry(NS + '.Regulator');
        })
        .then(function(regulatorRegistry){
            return regulatorRegistry.addAll([regulator]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Contract');
        })
        .then(function(contractRegistry){
            return contractRegistry.addAll([contract,contract2]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Plane');
        })
        .then(function(planeRegistry){
            planeRegistry.addAll([plane,plane2]);
            planeRegistry.addAll([plane3,plane4]);
        })


}
```

Comment: We have no details of setupDemo here - is this another Transaction in the BNA?  Perhaps the setup function can check some condiftion to see if it runs/re-runs the setup logic or just skips it and goes straight to your repeat monitor loop.

Comment: Sorry - see above edit for setup function. Yes setupDemo is another transaction in the BNA. If you look at the logs for the `dev-peer0.org1.example.com` however its gettign the error `No ledger context for GetState. Sending ERROR` when trying to update the asset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't going to fly :-)

Your setup transaction does not complete (return) before the monitorPlanes transaction (via the repeatMonitorPlanes) starts, so there is no data yet for the monitorPlanes to update.

As an alternative to having your repeatMonitorPlanes as a function in the model logic, you could write a separate API program that could have a repeat loop to call the monitorPlanes transaction using the [TransactionRegistry](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/client-transactionregistry) class from the Client API

Comment: I hope that pun was intended hahahah

Is that along the same lines as getting a client application to repeatedly call the monitorPlane() REST endpoint? I had something like that initially but wanted it to be automatically done from the blockchain and then just get the client to read the data from the blockchain.

Comment: Yes the bad joke was deliberate - sorry.   Yes a POST request to the transaction endpoint on the REST server is the same, and more straightforward too.

Comment: I enjoyed it all the same! Thanks for clearing that up for me :)